# Bcrypt gem in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I've just created a fresh **Rails 5** application.  I don't have any MVC's generated yet inside my application.

I added some gems to the gem file including `gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'`.

When I try to create a controller with the rails generator, I get an error.

This is the command with the error that I got:

**command**>`rails generate controller StaticPages home help`

```
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/rails17/rails_sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:156:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:156:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:143:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:60:in `generate'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

All I did was add gems to my gemfile, so I'm not sure why the rails generator isn't working.

I did notice that my generator stops working when I add the `gem bcrypt`.

Can someone tell me the reason I can't use my generator once I installed `gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'`?

Comment: Did you run bundle after adding the gem to the gemfile?

Comment: Yes, I ran bundle after adding the gem to the gemfile!

Comment: What other gems did you add?

Comment: I figured out a temporary solution from a link that might help others having problems especially Windows Users (https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/149). Appreciate the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

delete **gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'** from gem file and 
use 
$gem install bcrypt